# Logic App Try scope failing and not calling Catch

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want to update blob if it exists and create one if it doesn't.
I have a try catch finally scope block set up as shown.  The update blob is in the try scope.  The create blob is in the catch.  Once I have the blob I want to do an HTTP call which is in the finally scope.

The problem is that when it runs the try scope is failing as the file does not exist, but the Catch is being skipped.  The Try  scope has a lightly coloured x indicating skipped rather than a ! indicating the mathod has failed.  I think this is why the catch is not being called.  How can I fix?

[image: Scope Block]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a Terminate Action elsewhere in the logic app which ran if the previous action succeeded, failed or was skipped.  Oops.